# firebase real time database takes a long time to load data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase realtime database is taking a long time to load data. Here's a screenshot of the data that I have in the database. What can I do to optimize the loading? Also are there other places that I can store the data other than firebase? The data is 3.8MB in size, and has the following structure

```
{"10-happier": {body: "test"}, "zero-to-one": {body: "test2"}}
```

[image]

Here's my code

```
 var defer = Q.defer();
 app.database().ref('content').once('value').then(snapshot => {
   if (snapshot && snapshot.val()) {
       defer.resolve(snapshot.val());
   } else {
       defer.resolve({});
   }
}).catch( error => {
   defer.reject(error);
});
return defer.promise;
```

Comment: are those 3.8 MB all you need for your client ? Or you just need some data of those 3.8 MB ?

Comment: Please show your code to get this data.

Comment: I need all 3.8MB

Comment: @Ashish I added the code

Comment: value is node name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to optimize a query like this.  When you fetch an entire node:

```
app.database().ref('content').once('value')
```

The SDK will download everything, and it will take as long as it takes to get the whole thing.  The total performance is going to be determined by the speed of the client's connection to the server.  If you want the query to be faster, your only  viable option is to get a faster connection to Realtime Database.

Alternatively, you can bypass the use of a database altogether and use a different method of storage that involves some form of compression or CDN to deliver the content more efficiently for the end user.  Since recommendations for software and services are off-topic for Stack Overflow, you will have to do some research to figure out what your options are and what will work best for your specific situation.